# Wait for a function with a task to be completed before continuing

Tags: c#, async-await, task

How do you wait until a function with a task inside is done before continuing?

```
public void A()
{
    Debug.Log("before")
    CopyInfoFromDB();
    Debug.Log("after") 
}

public void CopyInfoFromDB()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference(path)
             .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
             {
                 if (task.IsFaulted)
                 {
                     Debug.Log("failed");

                 }
            name = ...// loading local varibles from Task.result
            });
}
```

I want it to wait for `CopyInfoFromDB` to be completed before printing "after". How should I write function A differently?

Comment: Return a `Task` from `CopyInfoFromDB` instead of void and await it in `A` by marking `A` async

Comment: Without being a specialist: I see two things: your so called function is not a function - and it seems, that there is an asynchrone thread running. I suggest to use a function and wait for the return value and to have a help variable, that is filled when the asynchrone function is ready.

Comment: I don't understand what does it mean "so-called function" that is my example

Comment: @JSteward Thanks for your answer, how can I solve it without returning a task? I have more code inside CopyInfoFromDB() - I deal with task.result inside that function so I can't return the task before loading variables, I don't need the task to return to function A

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Task.Result` it's a blocking call and can deadlock, await the call instead and that will allow you to return a `Task`.

Comment: That's how Firebase works for any method, we call the task and get results from Task.Result (if not failed) https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth?authuser=0

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use async-await - be prepared to make all methods involved in pipeline to be asynchronous as well

```
public async Task A()
{
    Debug.Log("before")
    await CopyInfoFromDB();
    Debug.Log("after") 
}

public Task CopyInfoFromDB()
{
      return FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
                             .GetReference(path)
                             .GetValueAsync();
}
```

In case `GetValueAsync` fails, exception will be thrown on the line where you are awaiting for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I solve it without returning a task? I have more code inside CopyInfoFromDB() - I deal with task.result inside that function so I can't return the task before loading variables, I don't need the task to return to function A

Comment: @SHAI, don't use asynchronous methods, I assume library you are using has correspondent synchronous method `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference(path).GetValue()`. If you are not planning to start using asynchronous methods in your software, then keep using synchronous. You will gain no benefits with asynchronous methods in synchronous code base.

Comment: I must use this code to connect the Firebase database, so it has to be GetValueAsync()  (they don't have a synchronous method and not recommend it for that use)